# How to check if the product is out of stock? [Odoo]

Tags: python, odoo

I created a method with scheduled action.

Object: 'product.product'

What I want to achieve is to send notifications to the purchasers group if the product is out of stock.
So far I have this code:

```
class product_product(osv.osv):
    _name = 'product.product'
    _inherit = ['product.product', 'mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

  def notification(self, cr, uid, context=None):

    product_uom_obj = self.pool.get('product.uom')
    partner_obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
    group_obj = self.pool.get('res.groups')
    partners = []
    followers = []

    group_users= group_obj.search(cr, uid, ['&', ('category_id.name', '=', 'Purchases'), ('name', '=', 'User')])

    for recipient in group_obj.browse(cr, uid, group_users).users:
        partners.append(recipient.id)

    for partner in partners:
        for follower in user_obj.browse(cr, uid, partner).partner_id:
            followers.append(follower.id)


    products = self.search(cr, uid, [('type', '=', 'product')])


    for product in products:
        for prod in self.browse(cr, uid, product):
            #check if the product is out of stock
```

So how can I check if the product is out of stock?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Stock of the Products using prod.product_tmpl_id.qty_available , but to get the qty_available field for product.template you have to install stock module also. So, in depends of **openerp**.py add stock also.

```
    for prod in self.browse(cr, uid, products):
        #check if the product is out of stock
        if prod.product_tmpl_id.qty_available<=0:
            #Send mail using message_post method
```

In your code for product in products: is not required. you can directly send the products list of ids to browse method

Answer (score 0):

To Send a mail only to the Suppliers of the Product while Confirming the Sale Order is

```
def action_button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    ret = super(sale_order, self).action_button_confirm(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        for line in order.order_line:
            if line.product_id and line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.qty_available<=0:
                partnerids = []
                for suppinfo in line.product_id.seller_ids:
                    if suppinfo.name.email:
                        partnerids.append(suppinfo.name.id)
                post_values = {
                   'partner_ids': partnerids,
                   'subject':"Send '%s' Stock of %s Quantity"%(line.product_id.name,line.product_uom_qty),
                   'body': '<div><p>Dear Seller,</p>'
                   '<p>Please send us "%s" Product Stock of %s Quantity as soon as Possible.</p></div>'
                            '<p>Regards,</p>'
                            '<p>%s</p>'%(line.product_id.name,line.product_uom_qty,order.company_id.name),
                       }      
                msg_id = self.message_post(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [order.id], type='email', subtype=False, context=context, **post_values)

    return ret
```

Comment: Hi Sir @Murali Krishna Reddy, but I need to send notification right away in order line. I updated my code in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913571/valueerror-odoo). I have new issue in selecting a product, can you check this out? Your answer will be my other option if ever. Thanks.

Comment: That link is Removed